# Cleaning old log files with logback

Tags: logback

I am using logback to configure logs in my application. I have SiftingAppender which creates logs per each job run. I need to automatically clean log files which are 2 weeks old. I tried to use RollingAppender, but it does not work since each log file name has unique job run id. Is there any other default logback configuration which might work for my use case? Thanks you for the help!

```
  <appender name="JOB_RUN" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">

<!-- This is MDC value -->
<!-- We will assign a value to 'jobRunId' via Java code -->
<discriminator>
  <key>jobRunId</key>
  <defaultValue>null</defaultValue>
</discriminator>

<sift>

  <appender name="FILE-${jobRunId}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/${jobRunId}.log</file>
    <prudent>true</prudent>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%level] [%logger{60}] - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>logs/${jobRunId}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
      <!-- keep 14 days of history -->
      <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

</sift>
```

Comment: Having a similar issue: https://cmsdk.com/java/a-logback-fileappender-that-uses-a-single-log-file-and-deletes-old-log-files.html
Related ticket: https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1432?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel
Seems this needs to be addressed manually for now :/